# Синтаксическая ошибка

Tags: json, javascript

Здравствуйте.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test JSONP</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var callbacks=new Object();

function getJSONP(url,cb) {
  var i;
  do
    i='c'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
  while(callbacks[i]);

  callbacks[i] = function(obj) {
                      cb(obj);
                      delete callbacks[i];
                    };

  var script=document.createElement('script');
  script.src=url+(url.indexOf('?')>=0?'&':'?')+'callback=callbacks.'+i;
  script.type='text/javascript';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Callback
function onSuccess(user) {
  alert(user);
}

</script>

<input type="button" value="Получить JSONP" onclick="getJSONP('http://vkontakte.ru/feed2.php',onSuccess)"/>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Данный код почему-то пишет ошибку `Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token :`.
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Что? Все незнайки?

Comment: С такими наездами вы были бы эталонным плохим менеджером.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

результат который возвращается при выполнении http://vkontakte.ru/feed2.php должен быть в формате JS, в данном случае вместо

```
{"user":{"id":7594127},"friends":{"count":0},"messages":{"count":0},"events":{"count":0},"groups":{"count":0},"photos":{"count":0},"videos":{"count":0},"notes":{"count":0},"gifts":{"count":0},"lang":{"id":"0","p_id":0},"activity":{"hash":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"}}
```

должно выводиться

```
document.write('
{"user":{"id":7594127},"friends":{"count":0},"messages":{"count":0},"events":{"count":0},"groups":{"count":0},"photos":{"count":0},"videos":{"count":0},"notes":{"count":0},"gifts":{"count":0},"lang":{"id":"0","p_id":0},"activity":{"hash":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"}}
')
```